# ModuleServer combined with modalDialog - modalDialog quits after first usage

Tags: r, shiny

In my Shiny application, I have the functionality to insert a new line of information, this is done via `InsertUI`. Then for every added line, the source of that line can be updated via an `actionButton`. The `actionButton` leads to a `modalDialog`, allowing the user to insert the text for the source there.

To prevent multiple lines getting the same source after updating, a `moduleServer` is used for the part around the `modalDialog`. That works well, with the only exception that after the first time the `modalDialog` is used (with inside an action button that updates the text after insertion), the `modalDialog` closes directly after clicking. Reclicking does give the pop-up again, but is somewhat annoying.

Any suggestions to prevent this?

Example UI and server with this behaviour:
`UI.R`

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  div(id = "input_add_div_block"),
  
  br(),
  
  # Input for the new line
  div(style="display:inline-block", # div inline-block is used to get two input boxes on the same line
      textInput(inputId = "input_new_line",
                label = "Give description of new line")
  ),
  # Adding a new line
  div(style="display:inline-block", # div inline-block is used to get two input boxes on the same line
      id = "input_add_div",
      actionButton("input_add", "Add new line")
  )

))
```

`Server.R`

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  data <- reactiveValues(
    lines = list()
  )

  observeEvent(input$input_add, {
    current_lines <- length(data$lines)
    n <- current_lines + 1
    insertUI(selector = "#input_add_div_block",
             where = "beforeEnd", # insert after last element
             ui = fluidPage(
               div(style="display:inline-block"), # div inline-block is used to get two input boxes on the same line
               # Adding input field
               numericInput(inputId = paste0("input_", n),
                            label = paste0(input$input_new_line, " - % of previous line"),
                            value = 10,
                            min = 0,
                            max = 100
               ),
               actionButton(inputId = paste0("input_", n,"_source"),
                            label = "No source")
             )
    )
    
    observeEvent(input[[paste0("input_", current_lines+1,"_source")]],{
      update_source_UI(id = paste0("source",n), data = data, n =  n)
      update_source_Server(id = paste0("source",n), data = data, n = n, original_session = session)
    })
  })
  
})

update_source_UI <- function(id, data, label = "Update UI", n){
  ns <- NS(id)
  showModal(
    modalDialog(
      title = "Update source",
      textInput(inputId = ns("new_source"), label = "Update the source", 
                value = "Assumption"),
      actionButton(inputId = ns("add_source"),
                   label = "Update the source"),
      "\n",
      actionButton(inputId = ns("cancel"),
                   label = "Cancel"),
      
      easyClose = TRUE,
      footer = NULL
    )
  )
}

# Pop-up to change the source of the funnel line input
update_source_Server <- function(id, data, n, original_session){
  moduleServer(
    id,
    
    function(input, output, session) {
      ns <- session$ns
      # When the user clicks "Update the source", the source is updated
      observeEvent(input$add_source,{
          updateActionButton(session = original_session,
                             inputId = paste0("input_", n,"_source"),
                             label = paste0("Source: ", input$new_source))
          removeModal()
          data$button_status[[1]] <- FALSE
      })
      
      # When the user clicks "Cancel", the modal is removed without changes
      observeEvent(input$cancel,{
        removeModal()
      })
      
    }
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few points:

- I've never seen `showModule` in the `UI` part, normally you use it in the `server`; it's interesting that it works nevertheless
- at least in your example, `n` is always 1, therefore you don't have unique `id`s which leads to problems
- I find passing `session` objects to modules to refer to something defined in the main `server` quite complicated
- I propose to pack everything for one line into a module and then handle the logic there. I think it's easier and you already work with modules.

My take:

```
library(shiny)

one_line_UI <- function(id, input_new_line){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    div(style="display:inline-block"), # div inline-block is used to get two input boxes on the same line
    # Adding input field
    numericInput(inputId = ns("input_number"),
                 label = paste0(input_new_line(), " - % of previous line"),
                 value = 10,
                 min = 0,
                 max = 100
    ),
    actionButton(inputId = ns("input_source"),
                 label = "No source")
  )
}

# Pop-up to change the source of the funnel line input
one_line_Server <- function(id, data){
  moduleServer(
    id,
    
    function(input, output, session) {
      ns <- session$ns
      
      observeEvent(input$input_source, {
        showModal(
          modalDialog(
            title = "Update source",
            textInput(inputId = ns("new_source"), label = "Update the source", 
                      value = "Assumption"),
            actionButton(inputId = ns("add_source"),
                         label = "Update the source"),
            "\n",
            actionButton(inputId = ns("cancel"),
                         label = "Cancel"),
            
            easyClose = TRUE,
            footer = NULL
          )
        )
      })
      
      # When the user clicks "Update the source", the source is updated
      observeEvent(input$add_source,{
        updateActionButton(inputId = "input_source",
                           label = paste0("Source: ", input$new_source))
        removeModal()
        data$button_status[[1]] <- FALSE
      })
      
      # When the user clicks "Cancel", the modal is removed without changes
      observeEvent(input$cancel,{
        removeModal()
      })
      
    }
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  div(id = "input_add_div_block"),
  
  br(),
  
  # Input for the new line
  div(style="display:inline-block", # div inline-block is used to get two input boxes on the same line
      textInput(inputId = "input_new_line",
                label = "Give description of new line")
  ),
  # Adding a new line
  div(style="display:inline-block", # div inline-block is used to get two input boxes on the same line
      id = "input_add_div",
      actionButton("input_add", "Add new line")
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data <- reactiveValues(
    lines = list(),
    n = 0
  )
  
  observeEvent(input$input_add, {
    n <- data$n + 1
    insertUI(selector = "#input_add_div_block",
             where = "beforeEnd", # insert after last element
             ui = one_line_UI(id = n,
                              input_new_line = reactive({input$input_new_line}))
    )
    
    one_line_Server(id = n, data = data)
    data$n <- n
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If you want more information, you can also check out [my tutorial how to dynamically add modules](https://github.com/jonas-hag/dynamic_shiny_modules).

Comment: Amazing, yes, that is way more logical than my approach. Packing everything for one line into one module also prevents the need for passing sessions. 
I've embedded this solution in the complete app and that works perfectly.

I'll definitely check out your tutorial, thank you!